# How to extend a class from child theme in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to extend a class that is in the Parent theme, but when I try to add my class in functions.php file getting fatal error, says the parent class not found. My class is something like this:

```
class MyClasss extends ParentTheme_Templates {
public static function header() {
    $type = ParentTheme_Global::instance()->get_header_type();

    get_template_part( 'mycomponents/headers/header', $type );
}
```

but I can use the same code for my class in my template file(I tried in header.php file) and it works, but this is not a proper way I think. So is there any proper method to do this. I can see in the codex:

> Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not
>   override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in
>   addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded
>   right before the parent’s file.)

is there any way to override this issue?

Comment: is the parent theme's class is pluggable? means it has `if (! class_exists ( 'ParentClass' ))` wrapper before declaration?

Comment: @shahin no, it is not pluggable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child themes are loaded before the parent, so you will need to define the class inside a hook that runs after the parent theme has loaded, so that the parent theme class exists to be extended. after_setup_theme would be the logical choice.

```
function mytheme_includes() {
    require_once get_theme_file_path( 'includes/class-my-class.php' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_includes' );
```

thanks @jakept